# What is the difference between sibilant sounds in Polish? (ć,ś,dź,ź vs cz,sz,dż,ż,rz)

Tags: phonetics, polish

I decided to start an online Polish course, but I am still confused about the Polish sound system.

My question is (I am still not so good in phonology):
What is the difference between the following pairs of sounds:
ć and cz, ź and rz, dź and dż, and between ś and sz ?

Comment: Specify which languages you speak, to let the answerers relate to sounds you already know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, *ć*, *ź*, *dź* and *ś* are **alveolo-palatal** consonants, all articulated with the tongue raised towards the alveolar ridge (located just behind the upper teeth) and the palate (the roof of the mouth behind the alveolar ridge):

[image: Tongue position in alveolo-palatal sounds. Source: Wikipedia]

On the other hand, *cz*, *ż*, *dż* and *sz* are **retroflex** consonants, all articulated with the tip of the tongue pointed upwards or even bent back (hence the name): [image: Tongue position in retroflex sounds. Source: Wikipedia]

Note that English *ch*, *s* (as in "plea**s**ure"), *j* and *sh* are similar to the sounds in question, but are palato-alveolar. It means that English *ch* is articulated somewhere in between Polish *cz* and Polish *ć*, and so on.

If you are familiar with sounds of Serbo-Croatian, it may be helpful to note that Polish *ć* is basically the same as Croatian *ć*, and Polish *cz* is similar to Croatian *č* (I'm not quite sure if the latter is retroflex or palato-alveolar). Similarly, Polish *dź* is the same as Croatian *đ*, and Polish *dż* is similar to Croatian *dž*.

It may be easier to tell *sz* from *ś* if you know some Russian: Polish *sz* is pronounced the same as *ш* in Russian "**ш**ут", and Polish *ś* is similar to *сч* in Russian "**сч**астье" (but somewhat shorter).

Finally, take a look at the transcription of these consonants in the International Phonetic Alphabet. It may be useful if you want to look them up in Wikipedia or find them in pronunciation charts to learn more about how they sound.

```
ć  [t͡ɕ]   cz [t͡ʂ]  
dź [d͡ʑ]   dż [d͡ʐ]  
ś  [ɕ]    sz [ʂ]  
ź  [ʑ]    ż  [ʐ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Yes, I know a little Russian, because my native language (Bulgarian) has much in common with it. We also have letters for these sounds, but only one for a sound: ш, ц, ч, ж. But I know that in my language many sound markings have disappeared through the ages. For example we don't have now nasal markings, which I know exist in Polish.

Comment: @KirilMladenov You're welcome. I think you wanted to write ш, дж, ч, ж (ц is a different sound, equivalent to Polish c). According to what I see in Wikipedia, all those sounds are palato-alveolar in Bulgarian, which means that they are the same as the English sounds I mentioned. So Bulgarian ш is between Polish sz/Russian ш on the one side, and Polish ś/Russian сч/щ on the other.